# Simple.OData.Client Error: No property or association found for Context

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Simple.OData.Client in a WPF application to consume web api 2.2 Odata services.

An `Simple.OData.Client.UnresolvableObjectException` occurs when attempt to insert a new record.

Error Description: "No property or association found for Context".

Code:

```
 var result = await Client.For<Movie>().Set(movie).InsertEntryAsync();
```

Could any one help me?

Comment: Do you have a property called "Context" in your "Movie" class? By default Simple.OData.Client requires all properties to be mapped to respective OData resource.

Comment: It was my mistake. Insted of referencing POCO entities, I have referenced to the entities generated by '`DataContextService` mistakenly. Now i re-referenced the POCO entities, and solution works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I tried to send inheritance object.

For example:

```
public class Entity{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
public class AdvancedEntity: Entity{
   public string AdditionalField {get;set;}
}
```

and this code threw the exception "No property or association found for [AdditionalField]":

```
await _client.For<Entity>().Set(new AdvancedEntity()).InsertEntryAsync();
```

The solution was at the tuning of default settings:

```
ODataClient _client = new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings(Constants.OdataServiceAddress) {IgnoreUnmappedProperties = true} );
```